# Sending html email displays as code in codeigniter

Tags: html, codeigniter, email

I have a problem with sending html email codeigniter . For text it is ok but on styling with html it always displays the code. Searched a lot and changed that email config array items to many. But results in the same html code. Please help me..

here is my controller function

```
public function contact_process()
{
    $name=$this->input->post('txt_name');
    $phone=$this->input->post('txt_phone');
    $from_email=$this->input->post('txt_email');
    $message=$this->input->post('txt_message');
    $config = Array(
        'protocol' => 'sendmail',
        'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
        'smtp_port' => 465,
        'smtp_user' => 'my_email_id@gmail.com',
        'smtp_pass' => 'my_password',
        'mailtype'  => 'html', 
        'charset' => 'utf-8',
        'priority' => '1',
        'wordwrap'  => 'true'
    );
    $this->load->library('email', $config);
    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
    $to_email = 'to_email_id@gmail.com';
    $subject = "Product Request Mail";
    $body = "<html>
            <head><title>Best Price</title></head>
            <body>
            <div style='max-width: 800px; margin: 0; padding: 30px 0;'>
            <table width='80%' border='1' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>
            <tr>
            <td width='5%'></td>
            <td align='left' width='95%' style='font: 13px/18px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;'>
            <h2 style='font: normal 20px/23px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; margin: 0; padding: 0 0 18px; color: black;'>Contact Mail</h2>
            <br />
            <big style='font: 16px/18px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;'> Name : '.$name.'</big><br />
            <big style='font: 16px/18px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;'> Phone : '.$phone.'</big><br />
            <big style='font: 16px/18px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;'> Email : '.$from_email.'</big><br />
            <big style='font: 16px/18px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;'> Message : '.$message.'</big><br />
            </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            </div>
            </body>
            </html>";
    //send mail
    $this->email->from($from_email, $name);
    $this->email->to($to_email);
    $this->email->subject($subject);
    $this->email->message($body);
    //echo $this->email->send();
    //echo $this->email->print_debugger();
    if ($this->email->send())
    {
        redirect('user/bestprice/contact/', 'refresh');
    }
    else
    {
        redirect('user/bestprice/contact/', 'refresh');
    }                
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't mention about mail contain HTML.

Use This

`$this->email->set_mailtype("html");`

Comment: I thought 'mailtype'  => 'html' in the config array is enough. Thanks @Abdulla